# Nginx finds css but doesn't load it into index.html

Tags: html, css, nginx, stylesheet

my nginx server serves an index.html file, which loads a css file and some js files. the css file is loaded (NO 404), but the style doesn't appear.

folders :

```
/src
    /assets
        /images
            ...
        /sounds
            ...
    /css
        /style.css
    /js
        ...
    index.html
```

sound and images loaded by the js files work perfectly.

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default/ :

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name jumpnrun jumpnrun.vm;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/jumpnrun.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/jumpnrun.error.log;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html;
  }

  location ~ ^/(assets/|css/|js/|index.html) {
    root /src;
    index index.html;
    access_log off;
  }

  location /socket.io {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://node-server;
  }

}
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Jump n' Run</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="game" width='1000' height='500'></canvas>
        <button class="sound"></button>
    </body>
    <!-- JS -->
</html>
```

if i go to localhost:8080 it gives me the index page but without any styling and the dev tools doesn't show me any errors.

thanks for your help!

**EDIT**:

The whole thing is in a docker container.. Now every time i browse to localhost:8080 nginx dies. error log is somehow not accessible..

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem and resolved it by making sure the `http` block in my nginx.conf was loading the proper `mime.types` mappings:

```
http { 
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
}
```

Comment: I had same problem, same solution.  Note that if you want to keep your types explicit, or don't want to rely on the mime.types file, you can just harvest types out of that file into a 'types { }' block in your .conf.

Comment: If it didn't work in the `http` block, try loading the mime types in `server` blocks.

Comment: It worked for me just by putting in the http block. I also had to remember to do a Ctrl+Reload for it to take effect. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks. Surprised this was not the default.

Answer (score 1):

try adding @charset "UTF-8";

at the top of css file
it worked for me. hope it works for you